# Visual Studio warning C4133

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, struct, compiler-warnings

getting a weird warning in Visual Studio 2005:

warning C4133: '=' : incompatible types - from 'PointNode *' to 'PointNode *'

struct definition:

```
struct PointNode {
  int x;
  int y;
  struct PointNode *next;
};
```

declaration and usage:

```
struct PointNode* pPointHead;
...

pPointHead = pPointHead->next;
```

The warning itself says they are the same types, why would it complain?

(unfortunately i can't tag C4133)

Comment: VC++ 2005 compiles its fine, no warning emitted. Are you using C++ or C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your struct should look like this:

```
struct PointNode {
  int x;
  int y;
  PointNode *next; // remove struct keyword
};
```

Declare and use like this:

```
PointNode *pPointHead; // remove struct keyword
pPointHead->next;
```

When you add the struct keyword, the compiler thinks that you are declaring a new different struct with the same name.